# MongoDB Node Driver updateMany filter by ID

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am experiencing an issue with the MongoDB driver in Node.JS.
When trying to update multiple users by ID MongoDB returns the error:

```
{"name":"MongoError","message":"Argument must be a string"}
```

When omitting the array of new ObjectId objects and using plain strings of IDs instead it returns no error but the identifier isn't pushed to the instances array either.

```
userIdArray = userIdArray.map(id => new ObjectId(id));

this.collection.updateMany({
   _id: {$in: userIdArray}
}, {
   $push: {instances: identifier}
})
```

When executing this updateMany function directly from the Mongo Shell, with an array of ObjectIds, the query runs successfully.

Thanks in advance.

---

This is the complete function:

```
  this.collection.updateMany({
      _id: {$in: userIdArray}
   }, {
      $push: {instances: identifier}
   }).then((result) => {
      callback(null, 'successfully added instance to users.');
   }, (err) => {
      console.log(err);
      callback(err);
   }).catch((err) => {
      new Report().error(err);
   })
```

The console.log(err) returns the error above

Comment: Have you debugged it to confirm exactly what is in userIdArray before making the update call?

Comment: Double checked it: console.log(typeof userIdArray[0]) returns an object.
console.log(userIdArray) contains the array of ObjectId objects.
Also tried new ObjectId(id).toString()...

Comment: Actually, I just realised that the query code you have shown is the *working* code. Could you show us the *failing* node/mongoose code? That would be the most important thing.

Comment: I added the complete function in my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out after a long search. 
My application uses multiple MongoDB Driver installations (different node_modules folders) due to its multi-tenant architecture running on multiple processes.

I used the DB connection from one installation and the ObjectID function from the other by using: require('mongodb').ObjectID;

All I had to do is pass the ObjectID function from the same place where I connected to the database.

Hope this helps others in the future.